# create yaml python from dict add 2 lines at top of dict

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am working to create a yaml config file that has some flexibility.  Ideally i need to create a blank config file with the fields.

The yaml configuration file needs to have two mandatory lines at the very top.

These are the mandatory attributes that need to be at the top of the config file.

```
Component: "groups"
groups:
```

however i need to add the flexibility to allow a user to specify how many groups they would like to add.  They may need 10 they may need 3.  The script will build out the following:

```
  group1:
    name: "Developers"
    description: "Developers"
    location: "US-East"
    code: "duse"
  group2:
    name: "QA"
    description: "QA"
    location: "US-West"
    code: "qawest"   
  group3:
    name: "Admin"
    description: "Admin"
    location: "US-Central"
    code: "acent"
```

The final config file will look like the following:

```
Component: "groups"
groups: 
  group1:
    name: "Developers"
    description: "Developers"
    location: "US-East"
    code: "duse"
  group2:
    name: "QA"
    description: "QA"
    location: "US-West"
    code: "qawest"   
  group3:
    name: "Admin"
    description: "Admin"
    location: "US-Central"
    code: "acent"
```

The challenge is i have the following script:

```
total_groups = int(input(f'How many total groups? \n'))
d = []
for i in range(0, total_groups):
    test = str(i)
    dtest = {
        'groups': {
            'group'+test: {
                'name': '',
                'desc': '',
                'loc': '',
                'code': ''
            }
        }
    }
    d.append(dtest)


print(yaml.dump(d, default_flow_style=False))
```

The output of the script is the following:

```
How many total groups? 
3
- groups:
    group0:
      code: ''
      desc: ''
      loc: ''
      name: ''
- groups:
    group1:
      code: ''
      desc: ''
      loc: ''
      name: ''
- groups:
    group2:
      code: ''
      desc: ''
      loc: ''
      name: ''
```

I need to one remove the -groups: and only have that at the top of the file.  I also need to figure out how to add the component at the top of the file as well.  I found the following and can't seem to figure out how to make this work.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...      d.setdefault('result', [])
...      d['result'].append(i)
```

Any assistance on how to remove the -groups: and make that a fixture at the top of the script along with the component: 'groups' would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `Group1`, `Group2`, etc. keys? Wouldn't it make more sense to either use the group's names as their keys, or else make it a list of groups instead of a dictionary of them?

Comment: currently the scripts are built to read through the config file like that. Here is the bit of code i am working with.  ```for k, v in result['groups'].items():
        name = result['groups'][k]['name']
        description = result['groups'][k]['description']
        location = result['groups'][k]['location']
        code = result['groups'][k]['code']```

Comment: i guess it doesn't really matter how i handle it as long as it comes out as a yaml file.  i was looking at a list - but it was recommended use a dict for it instead.

Comment: That code could be a lot simpler if instead of `result['groups'][k]['name']` you used `v['name']`. You're already getting the keys *and* values with `.items()` (and naming them `k` and `v`). Each value will be a group.

Comment: You cannot do `print(yaml.dump(d, default_flow_style=False))` in ruamel.yaml, and it is not the right thing to do in PyYAML either.  Alsways use `yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False))` instead.

Comment: @CrazyChucky - i will take a look at your suggestion on the results section as well i appreciate the input on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key (pun intended) is to look at the structure you want in your YAML file, and represent that in Python. Rather than thinking about this line and that line, think about what the structure represents. For the desired output:

```yaml
Component: "groups"
groups: 
  group1:
    name: "Developers"
    description: "Developers"
    location: "US-East"
    code: "duse"
  group2:
    name: "QA"
    description: "QA"
    location: "US-West"
    code: "qawest"   
  group3:
    name: "Admin"
    description: "Admin"
    location: "US-Central"
    code: "acent"
```

The data is a dictionary with two keys: `Component`, whose value is the string `groups`, and `groups`, whose value is another dictionary. In other words, in Python, it would look like this:

```py
{
    'Component': 'groups',
    'groups': {
        'group1': {
            'name': 'Developers',
            'description': 'Developers',
            'location': 'US-East',
            'code': 'duse',
        },
        'group2': {
            'name': 'QA',
            'description': 'QA',
            'location': 'US-West',
            'code': 'qawest',
        },
        'group3': {
            'name': 'Admin',
            'description': 'Admin',
            'location': 'US-Central',
            'code': 'acent' ,
        },
    },
}
```

You could build this like so:

```py
import sys

from ruamel.yaml import YAML

# Initialize the YAML parser/dumper.
yaml = YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = False

total_groups = int(input('How many total groups? \n'))

# Initialize a new dictionary to hold the groups.
groups = {}

for i in range(1, total_groups + 1):
    # Initialize a new dictionary for each group.
    group = {}

    print(f'Data for group #{i}')
    # Get the data for each group.
    for field in ['name', 'description', 'location', 'code']:
        group[field] = input(f'\tEnter {field}: ')
    
    # Add the new group's dictionary to the groups dictionary.
    groups[f'group{i}'] = group

# Create the top-level dictionary and insert groups.
data = {'Component': 'groups', 'groups': groups}

# Dump to stdout (which prints it).
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

(I've used `ruamel.yaml`, which was one of your tags, even though your code used a different format—PyYAML, I imagine? Same difference either way, really.)

However, I'm not sure this data structure is ideal; `group1`, `group2`, etc. are essentially meaningless keys. I would recommend instead either using the groups' names as the keys, or else eschewing keys entirely and using a *list* of groups instead of a dictionary. (Note that using names as keys would require all names to be unique.)

Comment: There is a caveat with reading the config file into `data`, which you circumvent by instantiating it as a dict. If you read in the config file, the value for `groups` is `None` and that needs to be detected and substituted by a dict (or as you IMO correctly suggest, by a list).

Comment: @Anthon I'm not sure I understand. The question doesn't involve reading the config file at all, only creating it from scratch, right? Where is `None` coming from? I must be missing something.

Comment: Correct there is no reading of a file when creating the yaml file.  The idea is someone who needs to create a blank config template can run said script and print to file the yaml file with the correct number of groups.

Comment: @Jared Oh, I see. Somehow I missed that you wanted to create it blank. This seems like an odd middle-ground to me, if I may say so. YAML is designed specifically to be easily readable and editable by humans. If you intend for your users to manually edit the YAML anyway, why not simply include an example template, commented out, in the initial config file? On the other hand, if you want the interactive script to output YAML for them, why stop at the correct number of groups, leaving all the fields blank? I assume your users can copy and paste if they realize they need one or two more groups.

Comment: this is 100% an anti-pattern.  The end users may not be familiar with yaml.  Essentially this is part of a contentpack to help deploy some software.  The goal was to build out a blank config if someone wanted to use their own.  We are already using cerberus to validate the yaml config is structured properly.  I have an engineer that has already tested the full script and one of the issues was he is unfamilar with yaml.  The design you suggested had an additional nugget i didn't think about which was asking for user input.  Which is pretty slick.

Comment: I can easily add an if statement to ask whether they want a blank one or work through the inputs you provided.  which is 2 for 1 special.

Comment: to your point of copy and paste to add another group.  i thought about that as well and that was the original design. The thought process is just provide a blank one with one sample group.  Another engineer stated some of the engineers that may use this are a bit on the lazy side or refuse to code anything even a copy and paste as they are more infrastructure.  your design actually works well and hits on all points.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Sorry, I hadn't properly read the question (as IMO you already answered it) and somehow interpreted that the mandatory attributes were read from a (YAML) config file.